# Yii: Innerjoin with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, yii, inner-join

wanted to get all my friendlikeactivity on my site.

I have 3 tables:

- follow_users (`user_id`, `follow_user_id`)
- videos (`ID`, `Title`, `Date`, `Likes`, `Views`, `Active`, `users_id`)
- videos_has_userlikes (`id`, `isLiked`, `users_id`, `videos_id`)

Now i want to create query to fetch all the Friends Like Activity of the user that is logged in.

Something like this:

```
$followers = Select * from follow_users where user_id = $MyId;

foreach ($followers as $userFollow) {

Select * from videos innerjoin videos_has_userlikes on videos.ID = videos_has_userlikes.videos_id where videos_has_userlikes.users_id = $userFollow;
}
```

I tried with a function in Yii, but i wasn't sure how to use an innerjoin with 3 tables..

```
 public function getFriendsLikeActivity($userId){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = '*';
        $criteria->alias = 'videos, videos_has_userlikes, follow_users';
        $criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN videos_has_userlikes ON videos.ID = videos_has_userlikes.videos_id INNER JOIN follow_users ON videos.users_id = follow_users.user_id';
        $criteria->condition = 'follow_users.user_id =:usersID AND videos.users_id = :usersID AND Active=:active AND videos_has_userlikes.isLiked =:liked';
        $criteria->params = array(
            ':usersID' => $userId,
            ':active' => TRUE,
            ':liked' => TRUE,
        );
        $criteria->order = 'videos_has_userlikes.date Desc';        

        return Videos::model()->with('users')->findAll($criteria);
    }
```

Please some help :)

Thanks!

Thanks @deez!

But i only want the like activity of the users that i follow..

Now i'm fetching al the data from the VideosHasUserLikes table, but there isn't a relation to the table followUser. There only a relation between the user table and the followUser table. Is there someway to also join these tables with the $criteria->with() ?

Now i have this code but i got an error because there's no relation to 'followUser' table..

```
public function getFriendsLikeActivity($userId){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = '*';
        $criteria->alias = 'videos_has_userlikes';      
        $criteria->condition = 'videos.users_id = :usersID AND Active=:active AND videos_has_userlikes.isLiked =:liked';
        $criteria->params = array(
            ':usersID' => $userId,
            ':active' => TRUE,
            ':liked' => TRUE,
        );
        $criteria->with = array(
            'videos'=>array(
                'together'=>true,
                'select'=>'*',                
            ),
            'users'=>array(
                'together'=>true,
                'select'=>'*',
            ),  
            'followUser'=>array(
                'together'=>true,
                'select'=>'*',
            ), 
        );     

        return VideosHasUserLikes::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }
```

Maybe something like that ?

```
 public function getFriendsLikeActivity($userId){
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->select = '*';
            $criteria->alias = 'videos_has_userlikes';      
            $criteria->condition = 'videos.users_id = :usersID AND Active=:active AND videos_has_userlikes.isLiked =:liked';
            $criteria->params = array(
                ':usersID' => $userId,
                ':active' => TRUE,
                ':liked' => TRUE,
            );
            $criteria->with = array(
                'videos'=>array(
                    'together'=>true,
                    'select'=>'*',                
                ),
                'users'=>array(
                    'together'=>true,
                    'select'=>'*',
                    'with' => 'followUser'=>array(
                                  'together'=>true,
                                  'select'=>'*'),
            ), 

                ),                  
            );     

            return VideosHasUserLikes::model()->findAll($criteria);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using CDbCriteria->with.

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'videos'=>array(
        'together'=>true,
        'select'=>'field1, field2, field3',
    ),
    'videos.likes'=>array(
        'together'=>true,
        'select'=>'field1, field2, field3',
    ),        
);
```

You can then reference it like $model->videos->field1, or $model->videos->likes->field1.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#with-detail

EDIT:

You should show your relations for more help, but I think what you want is to set up a HAS_MANY relation from user to user_likes, then include it in the with.

Comment: Thanks! My queries looks like this.. But i have no idea how to write him in Yii

-> Select * from videos JOIN videos_has_userlikes ON videos.ID = videos_has_userlikes.videos_id WHERE active = true AND videos_has_userlikes.users_id IN (SELECT follow_user_id FROM follow_users JOIN users ON follow_users.user_id = users.id WHERE user_id = 1 AND isliked = true);